# SQL Insert from DB1 to DB2 using JOIN on another table and avoid specifying column names

Tags: sql, database, join, names

I was searching before and couldn't find any answers. 
Let's put a scenario where we have 2 tables: 
 
- Customer 
 
- Order 
 
And 2 Databases: 
- DB1 
- DB2

### Customer:

- ID int
- Name varchar

### Order :

- ID int
- CustomerID int

DB1 and DB2 have the same tables structure and contains different data. 
Now let's say i want to run this query:

```
 INSERT INTO
    DB1.dbo.Order
 SELECT
    ID, CustomerID
 FROM 
    DB2.dbo.Order AS db2Order
    LEFT JOIN
    DB2.dbo.Customer AS db2Cust
 ON 
    db2Order.CustomerID = db2Cust.ID
```

This query works as expected. Now let's put up a scenario where you have more than 20 columns on a table and you don't want to go through and specify all of them, I want to do something like that:

```
INSERT INTO
    DB1.dbo.Order
 SELECT
 (
    SELECT COLUMN_NAME
    FROM DB1.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE TABLE_NAME = N'Order'
 )
 FROM 
    DB2.dbo.Order AS db2Order
    LEFT JOIN
    DB2.dbo.Customer AS db2Cust
 ON 
    db2Order.CustomerID = db2Cust.ID
```

Because we JOIN the tables we must specify the columns since they won't match with the Order table structure since we trying to insert, we must satisfy this exception: 
`Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.`

Is there a workaround through this? I would be happy to hear if anyone have any idea please.
Thanks for your time reading this!

Comment: Depends on the SQL dialect. Some dialects support Natural Joins. They can be dangerous so understand the implications before using them even if your dialect supports them.

Comment: Hey Aluan, I'm using MSSQL in that case. I'm 100% certain they are identical just that the other table contains specific data that i need from an old database backup. I can go through the manually way, but i rather learn something new and see how would it be possible to go through that road.

Comment: You mean T-SQL? Then no, natural joins are not supported,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @GordonLinoff pointing out for me about dynamic SQL, here is my solution:

```
DECLARE @CustomerID SMALLINT = 201,
        @ID         SMALLINT = 14007

DECLARE @columns AS NVARCHAR(1500) = '',
        @params  AS NVARCHAR(1000),
        @query   AS NVARCHAR(2000)

SELECT @columns += COLUMN_NAME + ',' FROM DB1.dbo.Order.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = N'Order'
SELECT @columns = SUBSTRING(@columns, 0, LEN(@columns))

SET @params = '@CustomerID smallint, @ID smallint'
SET @query = 'INSERT INTO 
    DB1.dbo.Order
SELECT
    %s
FROM 
    DB2.dbo.Order AS db2Order
    LEFT JOIN
    DB2.dbo.Customer AS db2Cust
ON 
    db2Order.CustomerID = db2Cust.ID
WHERE 
    db2Order.CustomerID = @CustomerID AND db2Cust.ID = @ID'
EXEC sp_addmessage 50001, 16, @query, NULL, NULL, 'replace'
SET @query = FORMATMESSAGE(50001, @columns)
EXEC sp_executesql @query, @params, @CustomerID=@CustomerID, @ID=@ID
```

I use the sp_addmessage in here so i can use the FORMATMESSAGE function since in SQL version < 2012, formatmessage func doesn't support to be  used strings directly. Hope that helps someone!

Answer (score -1):

First when writing an insert, list all the columns.  And when you have more than one column in a query, use table alises:

```
INSERT INTO DB1.dbo.Order(Id, CustomerId)
    SELECT c.ID, c.CustomerID
    FROM DB2.dbo.Order o LEFT JOIN
         DB2.dbo.Customer c
         ON o.CustomerID = c.ID;
```

Then, it seems highly unlikely that you want an `INSERT` in this case (I mean, the `JOIN` is probably not not even necessary), but that is another matter.

The tables and columns in a SQL query need to be chosen *explicitly*.  If you want to treat a query as a string, where you can just substitute parts of the string, you can do that.  It is called dynamic SQL and in SQL Server, you would execute it using `sp_executesql`.

Instead, just query the database for the columns and put them into the query yourself.  Be sure that you have a very good grasp of SQL before learning dynamic SQL.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Gordon. In the example statement the JOIN not being used, but i use it where i set a condition after. Tried to make it as short as possible and less to read. Now regarding the sp_executesql, i did some reading about it, but i still don't see how would i actually use it in the specific example i put in the original post. I'm coming from OOP background, that's why I'm trying to go through that way. I wonder if there is a way to do it implicitly rather than explicitly?

Comment: @GiladReich . . . OOP is not going to help.  All those nice abstractions and simplifications provided by object models *could have* been incorporated into a cleaner database access language -- but they were invented afterwards and SQL is rather widespread.  Learn to do it the "SQL" way; and then don't apply those lessons to your other programming.

Comment: I think i should've focus the post title to more like: how would i format the  SELECT COLUMN_NAME
 FROM DB1.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
 WHERE TABLE_NAME = N'Order'
To treat it as a string, so i can use it as a sub query instead of *. Is it even possible?

Comment: @GiladReich . . . As I state in this answer, it is possible using dynamic SQL.  Before learning dynamic SQL, I would recommend that you have a strong foundation in SQL queries.

Comment: I didn't downvote. In fact i can't even due to my reputation in stackoverflow is limited to post in certain topics as answer since it needs more than 50+.
I'll check more about dynamic SQL. Thanks.

Comment: @GiladReich . . . I know you didn't.  I think this answers your question accurately, and don't understand why it would attract a downvote.

Comment: thanks for your tips, After playing around with dynamic sql functionality, I posted the solution.